# Transform array of arrays/objects into JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js

I cannot wrap my head around this problem. Here is how my array is logically built:

```
array1 = [ [array2], [array3], [array4] ... [array17] ]
array2 = [ ['obj1'], ['obj2'], ['obj3'] ... ['obj30'] ]
...
...
obj1 = ({prop1 : 'string1'}, { prop2 : 'string2'}, {prop3 : 'string3'} ... {prop30 : 'string30'}) 
obj2 = ({prop1 : 'string1'}, { prop2 : 'string2'}, {prop3 : 'string3'} ... {prop30 : 'string30'}) 
obj3 = ({prop1 : 'string1'}, { prop2 : 'string2'}, {prop3 : 'string3'} ... {prop30 : 'string30'}) 
...
...
obj30 = ({prop1 : 'string1'}, { prop2 : 'string2'}, {prop3 : 'string3'} ... {prop30 : 'string30'})
```

I want to flatten it into a JSON object like :

```
{"array1":[
    { "array2":[
        {"obj1":[
            {"prop1" : "string1",
             "prop2" : "string2"
            }
        }]
    }]
]}
```

Here is what I came up with:

```
for (i=0; i < array1; i++) {

  var count = 0

  while (count < array1[0].length) {
    var jsonObj = {
      array[i] : {
        array[count] : {
          obj[count] : {
            'prop1' : 'string1'
          }
        }
      }
    }
    count++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include the code / a [mcve] in the question itself. Let us know what the specific problem is / where you got stuck. Makes it easier for us to help you, and will keep the question more relevant to future visitors.

Comment: Your code is missing at least one `}`. Please fix it where it is wrong.

Comment: perhaps worth having a look at underscorejs's flatten function http://underscorejs.org/#flatten

Comment: First please implement a fiddle or plunker.
Am assuming that
You can play very with objects and arrays while using 


  [1]: http://underscorejs.org/
  [2]: http://lodash.com/

Comment: If you're just trying to flatten your array of arrays into a single array, you can read this [Merge/flatten an array of arrays in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: Sorry for the confusing question.. I attempting simplifying and clarifying. Please see above.

Answer (score 0):

You could either push all `responseData.res` while looping over `responses`

```
secondRes.push.apply(secondRes, responseData.res)
```

Or flatten `firstRes` afterwards using `concat`

```
var secondRes = firstRes.concat.apply([], firstRes);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the question is a bit confusing. But if you want to create an array of arrays out from an array of objects, this is how you do it.

```
secondArray=[];

firstArray.map((object, key) => {

 let innerArray = [];

 for (let prop in object){

  innerArray.push(object[prop])

 }

 secondArray.push(newArray);

});
```